# Javascript page location based on input box

Tags: javascript, html, url, input

I have an input box where you enter a word, and it takes you to that page with ".html" appended after it when you click a button.

```
    <input type="button" id="button" name="button" value="GO" onclick="password(this.form)">
    <input type="text" id="answerbox" name="answerbox">
```

My JavaScript is:

```
function password() {
   var password =this.document.answerarea.answerbox.value
   if (password) { this.location.href = password + ".html"; }}
```

this works when you click the button, but when you press enter the page reloads with the answer wrtitten after the url (for example, /index.html?answerbox=hello)
Is there a way to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: You do realize you're passing in a parameter to a function that takes no parameter. Also, the `enter` key is most likely triggering your forms default action method (which is to `POST`)

Comment: @tymeJV oh, learned this from a tutorial. Guess it was a crappy one, weird. Would there be a better way to activate the function other than when the button is pushed, like, when the page is reloaded?

Comment: Use the `submit` event of the form.

Comment: @TimWolla Thanks! How would I write this?

Comment: `<form onsubmit="yadayada">` should work.

Comment: @TimWolla I found this, but it seems it still doesn't work. I have `<form onsubmit="password()">` but it just gives me ?answerbox=hello&button=GO (GO is the button's value)